# Android Restful API retrofit fetching data on Create method but not display

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio, retrofit

Here is complete code
(In first activity two values are taken from spinner and through a function data sent to second activity)

First Activity:

```
public class FindBloodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String API = "http://abdolqadir-001-site1.ctempurl.com/Account.svc";
    TextView t;
    Spinner spbgid;
    Spinner spcityid;
    ProgressBar pro;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_blood);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        pro=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        pro.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spbgid=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBG);
        spcityid=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);
        t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    public void SearchOn(View v)  {
        String BGId = Integer.toString(spbgid.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
        String CityId =Integer.toString(spcityid.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchResult2.class);
        intent.putExtra("bid",BGId);
        intent.putExtra("cid",CityId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Second Activity: In second activity on tt.append(string.toString()); working fine, but when i add below code than application terminated if i try to debug than also application terminate.

```
public class SearchResult2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    String API = "http://abdolqadir-001-site1.ctempurl.com/Account.svc";
    Spinner sp;
    TextView t;
    TextView tt;
    public int totalUsersCount = 0;
    String[] allUserNames;
    String[] allUserContacts;
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result2);
        tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        tt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String BGId = extras.getString("bid");
        String CityId = extras.getString("cid");
        tt.setText("");
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API).build();
        final gitapi git = restAdapter.create(gitapi.class);
        git.SearchUsers(BGId, CityId, new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String string, Response response) {
                    tt.append(string.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                tt.setText("No User Found");
            }
        });
            String bigArray = tt.getText().toString();
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
            bigArray = bigArray.substring(0, bigArray.length() - 1);
            totalUsersCount = bigArray.split(",").length;
            listView.clearTextFilter();
            if (totalUsersCount > 0)
            {
                String[] allUsers = new String[totalUsersCount];
                allUsers = bigArray.split(",");
                allUserNames = new String[totalUsersCount];
                allUserContacts = new String[totalUsersCount];
                String[] temp = new String[3];
                for (int i = 0; i < totalUsersCount; i++) {
                    temp = allUsers[i].split("-");
                    allUserNames[i] = temp[1];
                    allUserContacts[i] = temp[2];
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allUserNames);
                listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        SendSMS(position);
                    }
                });
            }
    }
}
```

This is log

```
02-08 12:40:51.433 9970-10008/com.example.abdulqadir.bd I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-08 12:40:51.457 9970-10008/com.example.abdulqadir.bd W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
02-08 12:40:51.458 9970-9970/com.example.abdulqadir.bd W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
02-08 12:40:51.548 9970-10008/com.example.abdulqadir.bd E/hwaps: APS: SSR : The platform cannot support SSR !: 0x0,0x0,8
```

This code below is working fine for me but when i changed this to above than getting errors, here is code please check

```
public class FindBloodActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String API = "http://abdolqadir-001-site1.ctempurl.com/Account.svc";
    TextView t;
    Spinner spbgid;
    Spinner spcityid;
    ProgressBar pro;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_blood);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        pro=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        pro.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spbgid=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBG);
        spcityid=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocation);
        t.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    public void SearchOn(View v)  {
        String BGId = Integer.toString(spbgid.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
        String CityId =Integer.toString(spcityid.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
        SearchAllUsers(BGId.toString(), CityId.toString());
    }
    public void SearchAllUsers(String BGId,String CityId) {
        t.setText("");
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API).build();
        final gitapi git= restAdapter.create(gitapi.class);
        git.SearchUsers(BGId,CityId,new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String string, Response response) {
                t.append(string.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                t.setText("No User Found");
            }
        });
    }
    public void Search(View v){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(9000);
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchResult.class);
            intent.putExtra("users",t.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class SearchResult2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    String API = "http://abdolqadir-001-site1.ctempurl.com/Account.svc";
    Spinner sp;
    TextView t;
    TextView tt;
    public int totalUsersCount = 0;
    String[] allUserNames;
    String[] allUserContacts;
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result2);
        tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
        tt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String BGId = extras.getString("bid");
        String CityId = extras.getString("cid");
        tt.setText("");
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API).build();
        final gitapi git = restAdapter.create(gitapi.class);
        git.SearchUsers(BGId, CityId, new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String string, Response response) {
                    tt.append(string.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                tt.setText("No User Found");
            }
        });
            String bigArray = tt.getText().toString();
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
            bigArray = bigArray.substring(0, bigArray.length() - 1);
            totalUsersCount = bigArray.split(",").length;
            listView.clearTextFilter();
            if (totalUsersCount > 0)
            {
                String[] allUsers = new String[totalUsersCount];
                allUsers = bigArray.split(",");
                allUserNames = new String[totalUsersCount];
                allUserContacts = new String[totalUsersCount];
                String[] temp = new String[3];
                for (int i = 0; i < totalUsersCount; i++) {
                    temp = allUsers[i].split("-");
                    allUserNames[i] = temp[1];
                    allUserContacts[i] = temp[2];
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allUserNames);
                listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        SendSMS(position);
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

Comment: add crash log ?

Comment: can you add the snipped for RestAdapter

Comment: paste error log here

Comment: Could you please add the crash logs as mentioned above in other comments?

Comment: 02-08 12:09:47.704 10778-10814/com.example.abdulqadir.bd W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
02-08 12:09:47.728 10778-10778/com.example.abdulqadir.bd W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
02-08 12:09:47.797 10778-10814/com.example.abdulqadir.bd E/hwaps: APS: SSR : The platform cannot support SSR !: 0x0,0x0,8

Comment: you have to understand that your callback is not necessarily called before the rest of your method.

Comment: this code is working fine on a function with activity one, but i wanted to fetch and display data on same activity, when i added this to 2nd activity, this isn't working fine

Comment: Please complete your code . please share xml also

Comment: i added complete code in answer, please check, thanks

Comment: @njzk2 maybe , check in answer i posted code which is working fine and other is not. let me know how to call callback from the rest of code, thanks

Comment: @AbdulKawee Code edited and added log

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you can try, use this code in `onCreate()`

```
 listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allUserNames);
            listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    SendSMS(position);
                }
            });
```

and where you were using the above code before replace it with i.e of inside of if condition

```
itemsAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> Why not do your REST call from the onCreate() method?
>   Also component.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); retains space in the overall layout. You could use 'GONE' instead and see if that helps or hurts.
>   And try have your URL and other components in different methods or classes. This can help a WHOLE LOT to keep the code clean and easy to find errors.
>
> > With all this said, after using breakpoints and running in debug mode which line is the error?